# Cursor.Position in asp.net page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, mouse

i am trying to change the cursor position with timer. it is working perfectly in debug mode but when i publish and host it, the code is not working.

The following code i used and i have imported windows.Forms`. I need to do this as it is a child lock application where when they try to click on any link it will drag them to other path and if they are adult this will be disabled

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 300, Cursor.Position.Y - 300); 
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

"Code Behind" is always executed on the hosting server, before any HTML is sent to the client browser.

You are moving the server's mouse cursor.

And, if you want to disable functionality if there is no proper authentication, make it unclickable in the first place.